# Rails form select does not preselect the existing entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, drop-down-menu, helper

**Situation**

I am writing a simple rails (a.k.a. no JS) form to create/edit an object `in_invoice`. One association is called `eur_object` & can be maintained via a dropdown which is generated via a `form.select` option:

```
<%= f.select :eur_object_id, options_for_eur_expenses, include_blank: true %>
```

As you can see `options_for_eur_expenses` is called to generate the options:

```
  def options_for_eur_expenses
    options_from_collection_for_select(EurObject.expenses.sort_by(&:name), 'id', 'dropdown_name')
  end
```

Saving & editing the object works fine generally.

**Problem**

With one exception: If you try to edit the object the value for the `eur_object` is not preselected based on the value selected at creation time despite being in the database. The drop-down is presented with an empty entry.

**Solution option: "Read the f********* **docs!"**

Rails documentation / google / apidock told me that the old entry will be selected based on the `id` so in this case the object's `eur_object_id`. But this is not the case. The drop-down is empty.

So basically editing & directly saving the object without observed change will lead to this association being set to `nil`. So editing and directly saving removes the association which is very unexpected behaviour.

I checked via byebug that the attribute is actually maintained.

**Solution**

I am looking for the right way to prepopulate the drop-down based on the existing value? Might be that the options of the select form thingy needs to be enriched with a "selected" option or so. The latter I thought will be automagically done in Rails but I might be wrong here!

Answer (score 1):

You most likely don't need to create the options yourself. That's only really needed when you're creating options from an array.

Use the [higher level form helpers instead.](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)

```
<%= f.collection_select(
  :eur_object_id,  # the method on parent and the name of the select tag
  EurObject.expenses.sort_by(&:name), # this should be passed from the controller 
  :id,             # the method to call on each item for the value
  :dropdown_name,  # the method to call on each item for the label
  include_blank: true
) %>
```

Comment: Thanks @max
 Will consider! Will this then auto-select the formerly maintained entry? Which it does with my suggested solution

Comment: Yes. It selects the option with the same value as calling the method.

Comment: then your solution is even better than mine I posted because you dont have to state the id exlicitly! Was lookimg for something suggested by you! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution in another stack overflow thread!

Adding an attribute (the `id.to_s` thing was added) so the caller of the method explitcitly states which `id` should be preselected to the call(...hence name should be actually something like `preselected_object_id` or something but anyways):

```
def options_for_eur_expenses(id=nil)
   options_from_collection_for_select(EurObject.expenses.sort_by(&:name), 'id', 'dropdown_name', id.to_s)
  end
```

This solves the problem I just posted! :-)